# Is it possible to save and continue during a mission?

Tags: dynasty-warriors-8

I am new to the Dynasty Warriors franchise. The battles sometimes take me a very long time, just for the second Wei mission I needed over an hour to get to Lu Bu, just to get defeated.

All that progress is consequently lost, and I had to start over. -> Frustrating.

Is it possible to save during a mission, or will this only save your progress in the campaign itself? (i.e. you always start at the beginning of a battle)

Comment: If I recall correctly you can suspend a mission in the middle but it's of the "Loading erases your save" sort, not a kind of "Quick Save" deal. Some previous entries have had this and I think this one does as well, but I'm not 100% sure.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After some testing, it seems that you can save at any time during a mission and continue from this point later.

However, while you have such a save active you cannot start another mission. So it is like a trimmed-down quicksave feature with only one slot.

I also believe that the save point is erased when you finish the mission.

Comment: note: From my experience with the console versions, when saving a 2 player game, you can't resume as 2player, only simple player (weird right..).